# Using Stripe and Parse APIs - how can I tell if the Current Parse User has an active subscription with Stripe?

Tags: parse-platform, stripe-payments

In my code, I can tell if the current user has created an account

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //keeps a user logged in
  var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
```

The Stripe customer object has a key value pair of status: active that I'd like to check to determine if the stripe customer has an active subscription. (https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_subscriptions)

Does anyone know how I can have Parse and Stripe talk to each other so that when ever the code checks to see if the user is logged in, it also checks if the user has a stripe subscription?

Comment: been trying to figure this out all day!

Answer (score 0):

it turns out there's a way to do that
here's and example in nodejs :

```
let stripeSub = await stripe.subscriptions.list({customer: customerId});
```